# Tracking multiple users in real time on a live location on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, location, pubnub

I'm searching for the track real time live location of the multiple users. Like Ola cabs and Uber Taxi live location. I try to find so many things but didn't find anything.
I also try with the Pubnub. but not success on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get longitude and latitudes from your list of users and add as markers in loop

Comment: Not like that I want to track the real time location.

Comment: May be this will helpfull. https://codeburst.io/build-your-own-uber-lyft-app-with-geolocation-tracking-for-android-devices-641ad5635f24

Comment: Use `FusedLocationProviderAPI`

Comment: 1) Learn how to get the user's location 2) Learn how to share and read data with e.g. Firebase or PubNub 3) Learn how to show a map and place markers in arbitrary locations on the map 4) Put all these together for your complete app. That's how it roughly would go, but that's too much for a StackOverflow answer. There's documentation available for all of this.

Comment: PubNub has a very in-depth tutorial for building an Android application that has this specific geolocation tracking feature for a taxi app like Uber or Lyft. https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-your-own-uber-lyft-app-geolocation-tracking-android/?devrel_so=tracking-multiple-users-in-real-time-on-a-live-location-on-the-map

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should have a WebSockets service,
So the accuracy of tracking is good & up to date,

You will use one client to send (long, lat) to the WebSockets service,

The other client will receive the latest updates from the sockets connection,
Then you show these updates on your map.

All that looks easy,
But It will require a solid backend service implementation,
To handle sockets failure,
Also a solid management of locations services on the client end,
As this will drain battery super fast.